# How can I return true only if one of a set of strings matches?

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to return true if the user enters only one of a set of possible matches. Similar to an XOR operator, but only one string out of the entire group may exist in the input. Here is my code:

```
if input.match?(/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/)
```

The following `input`s should return true:

```
+2 int
-3con
str
con
wisdom
dexterity
```

The following `input`s should return false:

```
+1 int +2 cha
-4dex+3con-1cha
int cha
str dex
con wis cha
strength intelligence
strdex
```

Comment: What about something like `'strdex'` as an input?

Comment: `strdex` should return false. I edited my question to include a few more examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably go with [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) and a simple regex so that you can understand what you've done later:

```
if input.scan(/str|dex|con|int|wis|cha/).length == 1
  # Found exactly one
else
  # Didn't find it or found too many
end
```

That also makes it easier to distinguish between the various ways it can fail.

Presumably your strings will be relatively small so scanning the string for all the matches won't have any noticeable overhead.

Answer (score 4):

The following are three ways to answer the question without creating an intermediate array. All employ the regular expression:

```
R = /str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/
```

and return the following:

```
one_match? "It wasn't a con, really"              #=> true 
one_match? "That sounds to me like a wild guess." #=> falsy (nil or false) 
one_match? "Both int and dex are present."        #=> falsy (nil or false) 
one_match? "Three is an integer."                 #=> true 
one_match? "Both int and indexes are present."    #=> falsy (nil or false)
```

**#1 Do first and last match begin at the same index?**

```
def one_match?(s)
  (idx = s.index(R)) && idx == s.rindex(R)
end
```

See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-index) and [String#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-rindex).

**#2 Use the form of `String#index` that takes an argument equal to the index at which the search is to begin.**

```
def one_match?(s)
  s.index(R) && s.index(R, Regexp.last_match.end(0)).nil?
end
```

See [Regexp::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) and [MatchData#end](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/MatchData.html#method-i-end). `Regexp.last_match` can be replaced by `$~`.

**#3 Use the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument and no block to create an enumerator that generates matches**

```
def one_match?(s)
  s.gsub(/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/).count { true } == 1
end
```

See [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).

Alternatively,

```
s.gsub(/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/).to_a.size == 1
```

though this has the disadvantage of creating a temporary array.

**To match whole words only**

In the penultimate example `'int'` matches `'int'` in `'integer'` and in the last match `'dex'` matches `'dex'` in `'indexes'`. To enforce full-word matches the regular expression can be changed to:

```
/\b(?:str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)\b/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to use a regex you may use

```
/\A(?!(?:.*(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)){2}).*\g<1>/m
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/Q2EUfyAyHVFtVB)

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?!(?:.*(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)){2})` - no two occurrences of any 0+ chars followed with `str`, `con`, `dex`, `wis`, `int`, `cha`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\g<1>` - Group 1 pattern (`str`, `con`, `dex`, `wis`, `int` or `cha`).